# Pass arguments to makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I would like to know if it is possible to pass arguments to the make command like this :

```
make file.class
```

So the aim here is to compile the java file and compile it from the file.java. I know there might be easier ways, but I don't have the choice (school work).

The problem here is I don't know how to pass an argument like that, and catch it in the makefile. Do you have a hint for me ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What exactly is the argument you'd like to pass? The name of the file?

Comment: let's say I want to compile just the file test.java i would run this command : make test.class
I know it doesn't make any sense, but i don't have the choice

Comment: You could put the contents of the makefile into a string and just fill in the name of the file. And then execute that new makefile

Answer (score 1):

Make is not a programming language, and a makefile is not a program.  At least, not the way you are thinking about it.  It doesn't accept general arguments and you're not able to write a makefile as a "program" that will "catch" arguments.

Make parses its command line and treats all argument as either variable assignments (if they have an `=`) or targets to be built.  That's it, there's no way you can change that behavior.

Luckily, that's exactly what you want: you need to write a makefile that contains a rule with a *target* of `file.class`; then when you run `make file.class` make will build that target using the recipe you provide.

See [this introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html) to writing makefiles and try to adapt it to your situation.  If you have problems that you can't figure out and the docs don't help, post your makefile as a new question in SO and describe *exactly* what the problem is and what you want to happen, including cut/paste of errors etc.